# How to get Firefox to recognize MIME types already established on a device?

Tags: windows, firefox, file-association, mime-types, content-type-association

When installing Firefox, only the default MIME types are configurable via the *Options* dialog box (currently 8 of them).

How do you get Firefox to recognize all the MIME types configured (in the registry) for a Windows device so that default applications can be set for each of those types within Firefox?